# Search only by time in DateTime field in Symfony2 and Doctrine

Tags: mysql, datetime, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I use Symfony 2 and Doctrine. In my database MySQL, I have a field of type `DateTime`. In my Repository file, by using `QueryBuilder`, I would like to search in this table only by date (without time) and only by time (without date), in my `Where` clause.

How can I realize this?

Comment: you can use native query and then it bind to entity

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can extend and register the **DATE()** function in doctrine2 to play with DQL. check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14188558/875519).

Now if you don't want extending doctrine2, here my solutions :

**Search based on date :**

You can get the interval between the datetime of beginning of a day and the datetime of its end, I already answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018055/doctrines-date-field-how-to-write-query/17019372#17019372).

This is the cleanest solution for the date (I think) !

Now another easy solution is to compare a datetime field as a string with **LIKE** operator, so you can also do that :

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')->where('u.createdAt LIKE :date')
        ->setParameter('date', '2013-05-06%')
        ->getQuery();

        $users = $query->getResult();
```

**Search based on hour :**

I don't know another solution with DQL than comparing as string (Unless you extend doctrine with DATE), here the code :

```
$query = $um->getRepository()->createQueryBuilder('u')->where('u.createdAt LIKE :date')
        ->setParameter('date', '____-__-__ 10:45:__')
        ->getQuery();
```

To remind you, "**_**" (underscore) means 1 character (and any character !).

Choose your solution ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, you're a genius, it work perfectly! Finally, I extend and register the DATE() and TIME() function. I've also tried your others solutions and all is OK!

Answer (score 4):

Part of my code which works for me:

```
$qb->andWhere('s.createdAt LIKE :createdAt');
$qb->setParameter('createdAt', $startDate->format("Y-m-d") . "%");
```