# Get data from doctrine from current date

Tags: php, symfony, date, doctrine-orm

I have an entity with a column `insert_date`. I should get all data from the table with the current day.

E.g. if today 10. May 2017  I'll get only 1 row.

[image]

```
public function getShopDayCloseWithCurrentDate()
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('shopDayClose')
            ->where("shopDayClose.insertDate ?? :currentDate")
            ->setParameter('currentDate', ??)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
```

I added function in the repo but I don't know how to use date format in right way.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17019372/2270041) answer

Comment: @Matteo Thank you! It works well!

Comment: Hi @Vladymyr you are welcome